# sqoop import complete but hive show tables can't see table

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, sqoop

After install hadoop, hive (CDH version) I execute

```
./sqoop import -connect jdbc:mysql://10.164.11.204/server -username root -password password -table user -hive-import --hive-home /opt/hive/
```

All goes fine, but when I enter hive command line and execute show tables, there are nothing.
I use ./hadoop fs -ls, I can see /user/(username)/user existing.

Any help is appreciated.

---EDIT-----------

```
/sqoop import -connect jdbc:mysql://10.164.11.204/server -username root -password password -table user -hive-import --target-dir /user/hive/warehouse
```

import fail due to :

```
11/07/02 00:40:00 INFO hive.HiveImport: FAILED: Error in semantic analysis: line 2:17 Invalid Path 'hdfs://hadoop1:9000/user/ubuntu/user': No files matching path hdfs://hadoop1:9000/user/ubuntu/user
11/07/02 00:40:00 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.IOException: Hive exited with status 10
        at com.cloudera.sqoop.hive.HiveImport.executeExternalHiveScript(HiveImport.java:326)
        at com.cloudera.sqoop.hive.HiveImport.executeScript(HiveImport.java:276)
        at com.cloudera.sqoop.hive.HiveImport.importTable(HiveImport.java:218)
        at com.cloudera.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:362)
        at com.cloudera.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:423)
        at com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:144)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:79)
        at com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:180)
        at com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
        at com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:228)
```

Comment: What version of Sqoop and Hadoop are you running?

Answer (score 3):

Check your hive-site.xml for the value of the property
javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL. If you do not define this explicitly,
the default value will use a relative path for creation of hive
metastore (jdbc:derby:;databaseName=metastore_db;create=true) which
will be different depending upon where you launch the process from.
This would explain why you cannot see the table via show tables.

define this property value in your
hive-site.xml using an absolute path

Comment: I think you are right. I met the same issue. I found I could find the tables depending on where I launch hive. GettingStart says "Metadata is in an embedded Derby database whose disk storage location is determined by the
hive configuration variable named javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL. By default
(see conf/hive-default.xml), this location is ./metastore_db". So please make sure launch Hive with the same location where launch Sqoop. Then you will find your tables.

Answer (score 2):

no need of creating the table in hive..refer the below query

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://xxxx.com/Database name --username root --password admin --table tablename (mysql table) --direct -m 1 --hive-import --create-hive-table --hive-table table name --target-dir '/user/hive/warehouse/Tablename(which u want create in hive)' --fields-terminated-by '\t'
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case Hive stores data in `/user/hive/warehouse` directory in HDFS. This is where Sqoop should put it.

So I guess you have to add:

```
--target-dir /user/hive/warehouse
```

Which is default location for Hive tables (might be different in your case).

You might also want to create this table in Hive:

```
sqoop create-hive-table --connect jdbc:mysql://host/database --table tableName --username user --password password
```

Comment: thanks wojtek, do you mean I should always create-hive table before hive-import ?

Comment: even I use create hive table, I still can't see table by show table command.

Comment: @elprup - no, you have to create it only once - when imporing data for the first time. But there might be import option that creates it automaticly.

Answer (score 1):

in my case it creates table in hive default database, you can give it a try.

sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://xxxx.com/Database name --username root --password admin --table NAME  --hive-import --warehouse-dir DIR --create-hive-table --hive-table NAME  -m 1

Answer (score 0):

Hive tables will be created by Sqoop import process. Please make sure the /user/hive/warehouse is created in you HDFS. You can browse the HDFS (http://localhost:50070/dfshealth.jsp - **Browse the File System** option.

Also include the HDFS local in -target dir i.e hdfs://:9000/user/hive/warehouse in the sqoop import command.

Answer (score 0):

First of all , **create the table definition** in Hive with exact field names and types as in mysql.

Then, perform the import operation

**For Hive Import**

```
sqoop import --verbose --fields-terminated-by ','  --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/test --table tablename --hive-import --warehouse-dir /user/hive/warehouse --fields-terminated-by ',' --split-by id --hive-table tablename
```

- 'id' can be your primary key of the existing table
- 'localhost' can be your local ip
- 'test' is database
- 'warehouse' directory is in HDFS

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need is to specify the hive table where data should go. 
add `"--hive-table database.tablename"` to the sqoop command and remove the `--hive-home /opt/hive/`. I think that should resolve the problem.